# $U,V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$; if $S\cup T$ is linearly independent for all linearly independent sets $S\subset U, T\subset V$ , then $U\cap V=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my problem:

> Let $U, V$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $S\cup T$ is linearly independent set for all linearly independent sets $S = \{u_1, ..., u_j\} \subset U$, $T = \{v_1, ..., v_k\} \subset V$, then $U\cap V =\{0\}$

Here is my attempt so far:

1. If $S \cup T$ is linearly independent:

   - Take any vector $x\in \operatorname{span}(S) \cap \operatorname{span}(T)$ so $x = c_1u_1 + ... + c_ju_j = d_1v_1 + ... + d_ku_k$ for some real numbers $c_i$ and $d_i$
   - $c_1u_1 + ... + c_ju_j - d_1v_1 - ... - d_ku_k = 0$. Since $S \cup T$ is linearly independent, $c_1 = ... = c_j = d_1 = ... = d_k$
   - So $x = c_1u_1 + ... + c_ju_j = 0$ is the only possible vector in $\operatorname{span}(S) \cap \operatorname{span}(T)$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here to show that $U \cap V = \{0\}$ since $S \subset U$ and $T \subset V$ so $x$ is not necessarily in $U$ or $V$?

I also attempted to prove by contradiction:

1. Suppose $U \cap V \neq \{0\}$.

   - Then $U \cap V$ must also contain a non-zero vector $x$, so $x \in U$ and $x \in V$.

I'm not sure how to proceed to somehow show that $S \cup T$ will end up linearly dependent for a contradiction

Comment: Let $S$ be a basis of $U$, and $T$ a basis of $V$.

Comment: If S is a basis of U and T is a basis of V then we know S spans U and T spans V, but how do we know that S is a basis of U and T a basis of V ?

Comment: You can choose $S$ and $T$ as basis of $U$ and $V$ because basis are linearly independent sets

Comment: Your first attempt can't be right because you haven't explained what $S$ and $T$ you are talking about.  You are only given $U,V$.

Comment: @Menezio, I thought since we dont know the dimension of S and T, we cant say that S and T are bases of U and V?

Comment: @pancakes You have the property **for all** $S\subset U$ and $T\subset V$ linearly independent sets; so you can chose the linearly independent sets you prefer (dimensions are not important here). 
In this case is really useful to choose two basis

Comment: If you don't want to think about bases, consider $x$ and $-x$ for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second attempt is on the right way: by contradiction suppose there exists $x\neq 0, x\in U\cap V$. Choose $S=\{u_1,...,u_s\}$ base of $U$ and $T=\{v_1,...,v_t\}$ base of $T$. Since $x\in U\cap V$ then
\begin{gather}
x = c_1u_1 + c_2u_2 + ... + c_su_s \quad\\
x = d_1v_1 + d_2v_2 + ... + d_tv_t\quad
\end{gather} 
for some $d_i \in \mathbb{R}$ not all equal to zero and $c_j\in \mathbb{R}$ not all equal to zero. So, subtracting the two equation we obtain:
$$
c_1u_1 + c_2u_2 + ... + c_su_s - (d_1v_1 + d_2v_2 + ... + d_tv_t) = 0
$$
where some of $d_i,c_j$ are different to zero; but this is impossible because by hypothesis $S\cup T = \{u_1,...,u_s,v_1,...,v_t\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 3):

We can prove this by contradiction without the use of a basis.

First notice that as said in the comments, the hypothesis is that for **any** linearly independent subsets $S\subseteq U,\,V\subseteq V$, $S\cup T$ is a linearly independent set.

Suppose $x\ne0$ is an element in $U\cap V$. Then $\left\{x\right\}\subseteq U$ is a linearly independent subset. Let $S=\left\{x\right\}$. Also, $\left\{2x\right\}\subseteq V$ is a linearly independent subset. Let $T=\left\{2x\right\}$. Then by the hypothesis, $S\cup T=\left\{x,2x\right\}$ should be a linearly independent set. But this is false: $-2\cdot x+(2x)=0$. Therefore $U\cap V=\left\{0\right\}$.

---

You may wonder if the conclusion still holds when the hypothesis is changed so that for some specific $S=\left\{u_1,\ldots,u_j\right\}$ and $T=\left\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\right\}$, $S\cup T$ is linearly independent. This is clearly false. For example, take $n=2,\,U=V=\mathbb R^2,\,S=\left\{(1,0)\right\},\,T=\left\{(0,1)\right\}$. Then $S$ and $T$ are linearly independent, and so is $S\cup T$, but $U\cap V=\mathbb R^2\ne\left\{0\right\}$.

---

Hope this helps.